# Filter NSMutableArray data by value into object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have this problem

I'm using Swift 2.0 in my project for iOS 9. I've created an object like this:

```
public class element_x: NSObject{
   var name: String!
   var description_element: String!
}
```

So, In a method I declare two NSMutableArray:  1) for all data and 2) for filter data, like this:

```
var original = NSMutableArray()
var filtered = NSMutableArray()
```

And during the process I populate this NSMutableArray like this:

```
let custom_object = element_x()
self.original.addObject(custom_object);
```

My question is: how can I filter original array by name value and saved in filtered array?

Comment: How do you want to filter them? What is your "condition" by which elements are stored in the filtered array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `NSMutableArray`. The native `Array` type in Swift is very capable. You can declare it mutable with `var` (equivalent to `NSMutableArray`) or constant with `let` (same as `NSArray`):

```
public class element_x: NSObject{
   var name: String!
   var description_element: String!
}

// Declare an array containing elements of element_x type
var original = [element_x]()
var filtered = [elememt_x]()

let custom_object = element_x()
self.original.append(custom_object)

// Find all elements with name == "david"
self.filtered = self.original.filter { $0.name == "david" }
```